# State managed in Context is showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm implementing a dark theme to understand React context. I successfully created a dark mode that saves mode to local storage and determined if the user prefers dark mode from local storage. 
However now I want to refactor to keep the theme state in context.
I have moved the code in a theme context however I get the error stating

**ERROR:** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'darkMode' of undefined`

I can't seem to work it out. I was under the impression that I could pass the state in this case darkMode and setDarkMode into my App component using useContext?

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ThemeContextProvider, { ThemeContext } from './contexts/ThemeContext';


function App() {
  const { darkMode, setDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}>
          <nav>
            <div className='toggle-container'>
              <span style={{ color: darkMode ? 'grey' : 'yellow' }}>☀︎</span>
              <span className='toggle'>
                <input
                  checked={darkMode}
                  onChange={() => setDarkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode)}
                  type='checkbox'
                  className='checkbox'
                  id='checkbox'
                />
                <label htmlFor='checkbox' />
              </span>
              <span style={{ color: darkMode ? '#9c27b0' : 'grey' }}>☽</span>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <main>
            <h1>{darkMode ? 'Dark Mode' : 'Light Mode'}</h1>
            <h2>Toggle the switch to change theme</h2>
          </main>
        </div>
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the ThemeContext

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(getInitialMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(darkMode));
    getPrefColourScheme();
  }, [darkMode]);

  function getInitialMode() {
    const isReturningUser = 'dark' in localStorage;
    const savedMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark'));
    const userPrefersDark = getPrefColourScheme();
    // if mode was saved -> dark / light
    if (isReturningUser) {
      return savedMode;
      // if preferred colour scheme is dark -> dark
    } else if (userPrefersDark) {
      return true;
      // otherwise -> light
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function getPrefColourScheme() {
    if (!window.matchMedia) return;

    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  }
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, setDarkMode }}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

Forgive my ignorance i'm struggling to wrap my head around this problem. 
Any help would be grateful thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only use

`const { darkMode, setDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);`

whenever some component above the one that uses this hook has a `<Context.Provider>`

However, you're using this hook inside your `App` component - it's not a child of your Provider.

What you can do is separate the children to a new component and use the hook there, or render your `<App />` as a child of your `<ThemeContextProvider>` (which means moving your `<ThemeContextProvider>` to another place)

*Option 1*

```
 const FooComp = () => {
    const { darkMode, setDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}>
              <nav>
                <div className='toggle-container'>
                  <span style={{ color: darkMode ? 'grey' : 'yellow' }}>☀︎</span>
                  <span className='toggle'>
                    <input
                      checked={darkMode}
                      onChange={() => setDarkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode)}
                      type='checkbox'
                      className='checkbox'
                      id='checkbox'
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='checkbox' />
                  </span>
                  <span style={{ color: darkMode ? '#9c27b0' : 'grey' }}>☽</span>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <main>
                <h1>{darkMode ? 'Dark Mode' : 'Light Mode'}</h1>
                <h2>Toggle the switch to change theme</h2>
              </main>
            </div>
)
    }
```

then in `App`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ThemeContextProvider><FooComp /></ThemeContextProvider>
    )
}
```

or  *Option 2*

in the place you're rendering `App` you do

```
<ThemeContextProvider><App /></ThemeContextProvider>
```

and you remove `ThemeContextProvider` from  `App`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class component and getting this issue
context is stored in a variable called context in a class component

```
    import React, {Component, useContext} from 'react';
    import {ThemeContext} from '../contexts/ThemeContext';



    class Navbar extends Component {

    static contextType = ThemeContext

    render() {
        console.log(this.context); 
        return ( 
            <nav>
                <h1>Content Apps</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
         );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```